# Row-wise loop across a range and copy column headers to another worksheet that satisfy a set criteria

Tags: excel, vba

Table 1

[image]

For the above table (Worksheet: Raw Data), I am trying to create a macro that reads through the rows (from row 2 to row 6) and checks if the cell value is less than 100 but greater than 0. In case true, two things happen:

1. the column header (city name) is copied to another new worksheet
2. that column gets deleted.

This is repeated for the entire range.

At the end of this exercise, the macro creates a new worksheet with clusters of cities such that in each cluster, the cities are the ones which have values of distance of less than 100.

Output

[image: Output]

I am very new to VBA scripting on Excel and would be very grateful if folks can help me out on this.

Comment: When you state '*I am trying to create a macro that  ...*', I am inferring that you have actually tried something. I see no code.

Comment: I suggest you share some code. Also look like your table and output per the question is the same too. Please update your question

Comment: both your sheets look the same